# How to make Kestrel console window auto close/reset upon each rebuild in Visual Studio ASP.NET Core web projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, kestrel-http-server

I'm using VS 2019. By default most if not all of the ASP.NET Core web projects use IIS Express as the host under Debug settings and `launchSettings.json`.

What I tend to do, especially for web API projects, is to delete the IIS Express profile and instead use the "Project" profile/launch option.

This simply opens a Kestrel console window upon execution, and I like it how logs etc are shown in the same console for easy diagnostics.

But the problem is, if any code is changed, and I re-build the solution/project (Ctrl+B, Ctrl+Shift+B,Ctrl + F5 etc etc), I get the "Could not copy..." messages in Visual Studio, till I manually close this Kestrel console window.

This is not an issue with the IIS Express profile at all.

So how do I make it such that I don't have to manually close that Kestrel window each rebuild? This seems like a natural/easy thing to do but I just can't find the options.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but just FYI: If you use IIS Express to launch your application, you can see the same output you get from a Kestrel console run inside of Visual Studio if you open the Output panel and select the ASP.NET Core application in the dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?

Tools → Options → Debugging → General → Automatically close the console when debugging stops

Comment: I swear I tried that option before and it did nothing... but just did it again and it's working now. May have forgot to restart VS. Also it appears to be working for "Start without debugging"/Ctrl+F5 as well despite the option name says debugging.